# How can I solve a performance issue in sql query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

All developers know that "IN" and DISTINCT create issue for all sql query. My colleague created below query but now He is not working at my employed company.PLease take a look below code. How can I tune up my query for high performance?

```
    SELECT  xxx
        , COUNT(DISTINCT Id) Count
FROM    Test (NOLOCK)
WHERE   IsDeleted = 0
        AND xxx IN
        (
            SELECT  CAST(value AS INT)
            FROM    STRING_SPLIT(@ProductIds, ',')
        )
GROUP BY xxx
```

Comment: "_All_ developers know that "IN" and DISTINCT create issue for _all_ sql query" (emphasis added) - that is a pretty broad statement. And so is your question. Start with looking at the query plan maybe?

Comment: *"All developers know that "IN" and DISTINCT create issue for all sql query"* Well that statement is wrong; you've just found one developer that disagrees with statement.

Comment: perhaps the reason your query is slow is because `IsDeleted` or `xxx` isn't included in a index, so the data engine has to scan the whole table.

Comment: Time to look at execution plan.

Comment: Please post a schema and sample data, with an EXPLAIN. Otherwise, we're just guessing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> All developers know that "IN" and DISTINCT create issue for all sql query.

This is not necessarily true.  They do hurt performance, but sometimes they are necessary.

The `IN` is probably not a big deal.  It gets evaluated once.  If you have another way to pass in a list -- say using a temporary table -- that is better.

The `COUNT(DISTINCT id)` is suspicious.  I would expect `id` to already be unique.  If so, then just use `COUNT(*)`.

The `WITH (NOLOCK)` is not recommended unless you really know what you are doing.  Working with data that might be inconsistent is dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

I have used used Sentry One Plan Explorer to help find the tuning points of queries I am having performance issues with:
 https://www.sentryone.com/plan-explorer

First you need to decide what good performance is in your environment, then find the worst parts of the query and optimize those first.

Last, consider how you are storing your data, look for places it makes sense to add an index if needed.

Answer (score 1):

1. better you have to create an index for XXX column